# Tmux find window configurations

Tags: tmux

I bound my `f` key to find words in current pane of tmux. How can I bind find window to a different key? I also want to do other things like naming a window etc. The way I have started setting my tmux config is to google for the functionaluty I need and copy it into my tmux conf. Is there a documentation on how to do all this on my own.
 How does one come up with a config like `bind-key s copy-mode \; send-key ?` or `bind-key C-a send-prefix`.

I tried adding `bind-key f find-window`  hoping it would bind `f` to `find-window`. But doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a list of the default tmux commands](https://gist.github.com/mzmonsour/8791835). As you can see, the default bind for f is not `bind-key f find-window` but `bind-key f command-prompt "find-window '%%'"`

The rest of your question is very unclear. You can `vim ~/.tmux.conf` and add whatever commands you want, such as `bind-key C-a send-prefix`. That line is in my tmux.conf and it works fine.

One possibility is that you aren't reloading your config file after changes (tmux won't do this with existing windows by default). You can use `prefix`+`:source-file ~/.tmux.conf` to reload your config file. You can add a command to your config to make this easier while you tweak it:

```
bind-key R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded..."
```